# Identity specification set to false

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am using `EF5` and `Code First` to create database. When Entity has `Id field`, EF create such field as `Primary Key` in database and set `Identity specification` to `true`(auto generated value). How to set `Identity specification to false by default`?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you don't want to use identity keys you have several options.

**Option 1:**  You can globally turn off this feature by removing `StoreGeneratedIdentityKeyConvention`:

```
public class YourContext : DbContext {
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<StoreGeneratedIdentityKeyConvention>();
    }
}
```

You can selectively select keys and change the behavior for them by either applying attribute or fluent mapping.

**Option 2:**  Attribute:

```
public class MyEntity {
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }        
}
```

**Option 3:** Fluent API:

```
public class YourContext : DbContext {
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
                    .Property(e => e.Id)
                    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
    }
}
```